# How to return a constant from a member function that (usally) returns a reference (to member data)

Tags: c++, matrix, reference, containers

I'm writing a classes for lower/upper triangular matrices (of `double`s). By taking advantage of the fact that an `n*n` triangular matrix only has `n*(n + 1)/2` [potentially nonzero] elements, internally I'm storing only that amount of elements, in a flat array member.

First of all, I have a base class for "normal" (i.e. dense) matrices, with `operator()` as a subscript operator that takes the row index and the column index:

```cpp
class Matrix {
public:
    // [...]
    virtual const double &operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j);
    virtual double &operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j);
    // [...]

private:
    std::valarray<double> data_;
    std::size_t size_;
}

// [...]
const double &Matrix::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) {
    return data_[size_*i + j];
}
```

For triangular matrices (I'll take lower triangular matrices henceforth as an example), in order to provide the same interface as for a regular matrix, I need to implement a slightly different subscript operator:

```cpp
const double &LowerTriangular::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const override {
    return data_[i*(i + 1)/2 + j];
}
```

The operator above is not complete though, since if someone asks for entries that are to the right of the diagonal (but still inside the theoretical matrix), another (unrelated) element is returned, but `0`should be returned instead.

Since references mustn't bind to local variables, I can't just `return 0`. Thus, how can I achieve this?

I was only able to come up with making a local static variable:

```cpp
const double &LowerTriangular::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const override {
    static const double zero = 0;
    if (j > i) return zero;
    return data_[i*(i + 1)/2 + j];
}
```

I could make the function return by value, but what about the non-const version (when the caller actually needs to modify the contents)? How can I make sure that the caller doesn't modify the `zero` static variable? This works, but it's a bit ugly:

```cpp
const double &LowerTriangular::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const override {
    static double zero = 0;
    if (j > i) return zero = 0;  // kind of ugly but works
    return data_[i*(i + 1)/2 + j];
}

double &LowerTriangular::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) override {
    return const_cast<double &>( const_cast<const LowerTriangular &>(*this)(i, j) );
}
```

So what is the best solution?

Comment: Would it be considered exceptional if someone requests data outside of the bounds?  If so you can throw an exception.

Comment: @quamrana That doesn't work when your return type's constness depends on which overload is being used, unless you use a `const_cast`. It's not a universally liked solution.

Comment: Or consider using `std::optional`.

Comment: If the result of your `operator()` is guaranteed to be meaningfully assignable, then cases where `j > i` are truly exceptional as they would not honor that guarantee. In that case, the right thing to do is throw an exception. If that's not the case, the user is responsible for verifying that the result is valid, which opens up many possibilities. The simplest one may be to just return a pointer instead, with `nullptr` when `j > i`. What's right really depends on how you intend to use your type.

Comment: Make the variable private or protected. This way it can not be modified by the user.

Comment: @NathanOliver That would definitely be an option, but I'd strongly prefer that the interface's behaviour was the exact same as for a general matrix—In fact, this class is a subclass of another class, `Matrix`. I would like functions working with `Matrix` references (who don't know whether the matrix is triangular or not) to be able to use the interface normally.

Comment: I would really consider @FrançoisAndrieux's answer, but prefer the `std::optional` option in case you don't want to transfer responsibility to the user.

Comment: @Anakhand You may want to consider not returning a `double &`, instead returning a proxy type that behaves as a reference to a double but that does the coordinate checking. A type that is implicitly convertible to `double` and assignable from `double`. Edit : You can then handle assignment to unsupported coordinates in whichever way you want. Though it's not clear to me what you want your type to do when someone tries to assign to an element that is not part of your triangle.

Comment: @Anakhand: Sorry, my bad.

Comment: _I would like functions working with Matrix references (who don't know whether the matrix is triangular or not) to be able to use the interface normally._ I consider this design goal somehow as dangerous also. A function writes accidentally values (!= 0) in the upper triangle which "vanish" magically so that reading back provides a different value than written. I would sleep better with the exception for write access to upper triangle which might be not thrown for the exceptional case of writing 0.0. (...the exceptional case from exception... ;-))

Comment: @Scheff That's right, I hadn't fully thought of that.

Comment: May be, a proxy would be the best solution to achieve this - like suggested in @FrançoisAndrieux' comment. The only drawback, I see: The returned proxy cannot be passed as argument where a `double&` is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your chosen optimisation is in conflict with the interface that you provide.

One approach might be to not return a reference, but a transparent wrapper that behaves like a reference. Something similar to `std::vector::<bool>::reference`. An example:

```
struct Reference {
    double* element;

    operator double() const {
         return element
             ? *element
             : 0;
    }
    Reference& operator=(double d) {
        if (!element)
            throw std::out_of_range("Cannot modify right side of diagnoal");
        *element = d;
        return *this;
    }
};

const Reference
LowerTriangular::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
    return {
        j > i
            ? nullptr
            : data_ + i*(i + 1)/2 + j
    };
}

Reference
LowerTriangular::operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) {
    return {
        j > i
            ? nullptr
            : data_ + i*(i + 1)/2 + j
    };
}
```

This does have same caveats as `std::vector::<bool>::reference`, i.e. taking address of the reference doesn't give you pointer to the double object. This could be one of the few cases where overloading `operator&` makes sense. But that can be counter intuitive as well, when the user of the API is aware of the wrapper and does indeed want address of the wrapper.

Instead of throwing, you could specify that attempting to modify right side of diagonal is undefined behaviour.

Comment: One thing of note is that this is not completely `const` correct. While you won't be able to directly assign to the result of `operator()(...) const`, you can copy the result into a non-`const` instance of `Reference` which will then allow you to modify the referred element. The typical solution would have two `Reference` types, one for `const` and one for non-`const` return values.

Comment: Would this type be covariant with `double &`? The reason that's needed is that `operator()` is an override of the corresponding virtual method in `Matrix`, which returns a `double &`. (I failed to mention that.)

Comment: @Anakhand this would not be covariant. If you have inheritance involved, you'd have to make all classes in hierarchy to return wrappers, and either have a hierarchy for the wrappers or have the wrappers use callbacks.

Answer (score -3):

When you return by constant reference:

Basic types (<= 8 or even 16 bytes) are usually returned by value in such cases (read only).
Consider returning **double** instead of **const double&**.

When you return by non constant reference:

You can check the boundaries and throw an exception if accessing out of bounds or do as in many standard functions such as std::vector::operator[]: if accessing out of bounds, then this is undefined behaviour. Just document it so that the user of your function knows he must check himself.

Note that overloads can have different return types so you can return by value in the const case and by reference in the non const case.

You could also store a "zero" in a field of you class and return a reference to it if accessing in the null half of the matrix.
You would have to set it to zero before returning the reference, just in case a malicious user changes it in the meantime.

Comment: Right, I should probably return by value for the const version. But for the non-const version, the challenge lies in the fact that I'd strongly prefer that the interface's behaviour was the exact same as for a general matrix—In fact, this class is a subclass of another class, `Matrix`. I would like functions working with `Matrix` references (who don't know whether the matrix is triangular or not) to be able to use the interface normally, without raising exceptions when accessing elements to the right of the diagonal (which aren't actually "out of bounds").